# Open a dll (get handle) in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm looking to load a dll library in c++, visual studio.

When I do I get error code 193, this is:
ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
193 (0xC1)
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.

The code is below

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

    HINSTANCE dllhandle = 
    LoadLibrary(L"C:\\LKG5000_DLL_ver1_10\\English\\64bit\\LKIF2.dll");
    cout << dllhandle << endl;

    if (dllhandle != 0)
    {
        cout << "Created Handle" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ":(" << endl;
    }

    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    getchar(); //Lazy way to keep cmd window open

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: looking at the path of dll, looks like it's a 64-bit dll but your executable is probably 32-bit. Your executable should be 64-bit too cause 32-bit apps can't load 64-bit dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the DLL path it looks like it's a 64-bit (WIN64) DLL.

Make sure your program that is trying to load that DLL is compiled for 64-bit target as well.
You can't load a 64-bit DLL in a 32-bit application or the other way around.

Read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d3fb8ed-fc3b-471f-b5a5-cb2cd08b2b06/loading-a-32bit-dll-into-a-64bit-application?forum=vcgeneral) for more details.

Comment: That's a great help - Thank you!